# Lightgun game (Mouse not in the middle)

Tags: modding

I'd like to do a small lightgun game.
So the mouse should not always be in the middle like in most ego shooters. The player should be moved trough a world and then shoot some enemies at a more or less fixed screen (typical lightgun game style like in Crisis Zone and others).

It would be good if I can just mod a game like Counter Strike, so I can use the models, animations, leveleditor and so on.
I did some maps for CS a few years ago and coded a little bit with delphi and the genesis engine a long time ago, so I don't really have that much experience.

Is it possible to mod a existing game the way I described?

Which platform could be used (if possible predifined models and animations and so on)?

Comment: Where is your actual question?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear. Can I mod steam or a similar game? If not, which platform do you guys recommend?

Comment: `Is it possible to mod a existing game the way I described?` yes

Comment: So WHICH game? Is there a tutorial or a related link?

Comment: Yes - http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xw56HhewI1A watch that video and it will show you how to create your own Garry's mod type game. It is scripted in lua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a high quality shooter. Use the Unreal engine.

> http://www.unrealengine.com/unreal_engine_4/

All the assets from the Unreal Tournaments are avaiable to you, for learning purposes. 
All you have to do is download the Unreal Develoment Kit, and install the Unreal Tournament Starter assets. Making any type of shooter won't be hard if you follow official tutorials. Gl on your light shooter :)